# Why am I getting `expected an indented block`?

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to insert an image into MySQL with Python.

```
 import mysql.connector
import base64

conn = mysql.connector.Connect(user="root",passwd="solomon",host="localhost",db="binarymanipulation",port="3306")

cursor =conn.cursor;
with open('/home/solomon/Downloads/javapic.jpeg', 'rb') as image:

cursor.execute('INSERT INTO images(id,size,image) VALUES('PYTHON',245,image) ')
conn.commit();
conn.close();
```

I'm getting `expected an indented block` while running this code.

What did I miss? What is the right way?

Comment: @GreenChili, please don't fix OP's indentation. You just removed the problem.

Comment: @MorganThrapp yes, you are right, rolled back.

Comment: oh dang now i need to go capitalize my answer again :P (just kidding)

Comment: ALSO NOTE THAT *notices case has changed. Softens voice.* the quotes in the string are invalid. You will need to choose which quotes (" " or ' ') to use to hold the query string, and use the other for the value PYTHON (which is to be interpreted by the database). In MySQL at least, the choice is arbitrary.

Answer (score 2):

your first line should not have a space to lead it

your lines following `with open("file.txt...` should all be indented

but you also have broken strings ... in your execute statements